# android chrome-cast media router action bar item hides after some automatically.

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Hi I am building sample chrome cast application in which I am am trying to show media route action bar button. My application showing that button in action-bar but it hides that button after some time here is my sample activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private VideoCastManager mCastManager;

private IVideoCastConsumer mCastConsumer;


     private MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem;

     boolean mIsHoneyCombOrAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;

     public static final String FTU_SHOWN_KEY = "ftu_shown";

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoCastManager.checkGooglePlayServices(this);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        mCastManager = getCastManager();

        mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {

            @Override

            public void onFailed(int resourceId, int statusCode) {



            }

            @Override

            public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() was called with cause: " + cause);

                Utils.

                        showToast(MainActivity.this, R.string.connection_temp_lost);

            }

            @Override

            public void onConnectivityRecovered() {

                Utils.

                        showToast(MainActivity.this, R.string.connection_recovered);

            }



            @Override

            public void onCastDeviceDetected(final RouteInfo info) {

            }

        };

        setupActionBar(actionBar);

        mCastManager.reconnectSessionIfPossible(this, false);

    }

    private void setupActionBar(ActionBar actionBar) {

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_logo_castvideos);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }



    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);



        mediaRouteMenuItem = mCastManager.

                addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);



        return true;

    }

    @Override

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        if (mCastManager.onDispatchVolumeKeyEvent(event,0.5)) {

            return true;

        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    }



    @Override

    protected void onResume() {

        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() was called");

        mCastManager = getCastManager();

        if (null != mCastManager) {

            mCastManager.addVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);

            mCastManager.incrementUiCounter();

        }



        super.onResume();

    }



    @Override

    protected void onPause() {

        mCastManager.decrementUiCounter();

        mCastManager.removeVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);

        super.onPause();

    }



    @Override

    protected void onDestroy() {

        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy is called");

        if (null != mCastManager) {

            mCastManager.clearContext(this);

        }

        super.onDestroy();

    }



    public VideoCastManager getCastManager()

    {

        if (null == mCastManager) {

        mCastManager = VideoCastManager.initialize(this, "4F8B3483", null, null);

        mCastManager.enableFeatures(

                    VideoCastManager.FEATURE_NOTIFICATION |

                            VideoCastManager.FEATURE_LOCKSCREEN |

                            VideoCastManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RECONNECT |

                            VideoCastManager.FEATURE_CAPTIONS_PREFERENCE |

                            VideoCastManager.FEATURE_DEBUGGING);



        }

        mCastManager.setContext(this);

        String destroyOnExitStr = Utils.getStringFromPreference(this,

        "termination_policy");

        mCastManager.setStopOnDisconnect(true);

        return mCastManager;

    }

}
```

I am adding button in menu.xml. It is working fine only thing is that after some time it get hide. These are my logs when it get hide. It calles `onRouteRemoved`

```
09-25 11:41:03.220: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(6045): [v1.10] onRouteRemoved: MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:ae6f7e130693a422e3ef22b9b76f1a5b, name=mobiotics, description=Casting Backdrop, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0, volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=572], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
```

Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Does the same happen with CastVide0s-android sample?

Comment: Yes. I have tested it in that application as well.

Comment: Yhen you might want to look into your networking setup; try this on a different network and see if that behaves differently.

Comment: @AliNaddaf sir thank you for help. I have check it on another device and it is working fine on it But on few other device it is not working. I don't know what is the issue. Thank you.